# 3D plot in spherical cordinates

Tags: plotting

```
Y = 0.04 *sqrt (5/(16*pi))*(3*cos[Theta]^2 - 1) + 
      0.08*sqrt(6006/pi)/64*((1 - Cos[Theta]^2)^3)*Cos6[Phi]

Theta = [0, pi]; Phi = [-pi, pi]
```

Need to plot `Y`.

Comment: Welcome! You need to take a look at some basic tutorials first - your code is full of syntax errors.

Comment: Go to this [support page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/?source=nav) and type in the names of those functions you are trying to use (e.g. cos, sqrt, etc.) to see what the correct syntax is. While you are there, look up `Plot3D` and `SphericalPlot3D` as well. That's really all you need.

Comment: It is so trivial that I vote to close as a simple mistake. The mistake is not looking at the documentation, which will tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing your syntax errors, hopefully  without changing your intent, and using [`SphericalPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SphericalPlot3D.html), I get

```
y[θ_, ϕ_] := 
  (4/100)*Sqrt[5/(16*π)]*(3*Cos[θ]^2 - 1) + 
  (8/100)*Sqrt[6006/π]/64*((1 - Cos[θ]^2)^3)*Cos[ϕ]^6
SphericalPlot3D[y[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, -π, π}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Is this what you were looking for?

## Update

1. `Cos6` is not a built-in `_Mathematica_` function, so I would have to have your private definition of `Cos6` to make a plot that uses it. If by `Cos6[Phi]` you really mean `Cos[6 ϕ]`, then the plot becomes

   ```
   y[θ_, ϕ_] := 
     (4/100)*Sqrt[5/(16*π)]*(3*Cos[θ]^2 - 1) + 
     (8/100)*Sqrt[6006/π]/64*((1 - Cos[θ]^2)^3)*Cos[6 ϕ]
   SphericalPlot3D[y[θ, ϕ], {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, -π, π},
     PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
   ```

[image: plot-2]

2. You can use the `PlotRange` option to set the range to anything you like.
3. I like PNG for saving plot image such as these.

Comment: Nope . its Cos6[Phi] not Cos [Phi]^6 . Also how can I change the range ?

Comment: Which is the best format to save as ?eps or jpeg ?

Comment: @pavan how is `Cos6` defined then? And asking what format to save in is mostly subjective and entirely depends on what you need the result for. I would say it is not on topic for this site, just as "do my work for me" questions are not on topic in general. Contribute some of your own effort, please.